# Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined at new Router in React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have this problem of `Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined
    at new Router`. I'm not able to understand what is going wrong in `react-router 4` or my code.

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var {Router} = require('react-router-dom');
var createHistory = require('history/createBrowserHistory');
var routes = require('./routes/routes');
debugger
// const history = createHistory();
ReactDOM.render((<Router history = {createHistory} routes = {routes} />), document.getElementById('app'));
```

This is what getting printed in console :

```
Router.js:31 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined
at new Router (Router.js:31)
at ReactCompositeComponent.js:292
at measureLifeCyclePerf (ReactCompositeComponent.js:73)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponentWithoutOwner (ReactCompositeComponent.js:291)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:282)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:185)
at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js:43)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (ReactCompositeComponent.js:368)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:255)
at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js:43)
```

I'm not able to figure out what I'm wrong here, please help.

Comment: Your history is wrong here. It should be `const history = createHistory();` and that's what you pass in to the `history` prop. So it should look like `<Router history={history}>`.

Comment: Post `routes/routes.js`

Comment: i dont think there is routes prop on react-router 4 for Router. check this https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/modules/Router.js